# rdstate() after extracting a value from a stringstream (and boolean type)

Tags: c++, boolean, extract, istream

(/edit : added 3rd issue)

To parse easily primitive types from various origins (aswell as possibly some objects overloading operators << & >>), I have created this template function:

```
#include <sstream> 
#include <iostream> //only for the debug trace
#include <typeinfo> //only for the debug trace

template<typename T>
static inline bool getValue(std::string value, T& result)
{
    //std::cout << "getValue : '" << value << "'" << std::endl;
    //std::cout << "type : " << typeid(T).name() << std::endl;

    std::stringstream ss(value);
    ss >> std::boolalpha >> result;

    //std::cout << "result : " << result << std::endl;
    //std::cout << "ss.rdstate() : " << ss.rdstate() << std::endl;

    return ss.good();
}
```

This template function takes a string, and will try to extract a value according to the given reference type.

**Output :**

For a boolean, with value "true" :

```
getValue : 'true'
type : b
result : 1
ss.rdstate() : 0
```

For a boolean, with value "1" :

```
getValue : '1'
type : b
result : 0
ss.rdstate() : 4
```

For an int :

```
getValue : '60'
type : i
result : 60
ss.rdstate() : 2
```

For a string, with value "blah" : (yes i know, useless for a string, but if i want to loop on several parameters with various types...)

```
getValue : 'blah'
type : Ss
result : blah
ss.rdstate() : 2
```

**I have here 2 issues :**

**1) boolean values**

To be able to read value strings "true" or "false", I had to add this "std::boolalpha" manipulator. But then I am unable to successfully parse '0' or '1' for bool type.

**2) rdstate flag**

In case of error when parsing (with the boolean issue for instance) , rdstate returns 4 (ie "fail").
In case, it is correct, it will either return '0' (good) for the boolean ; or '2' (ie "eof") for integers or string.
Can someone explain why this difference between these types ? should i consider "eof" as correct ? I assume yes.

Documentation of operator>> (http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/operator%3E%3E/) states that failbit is set for :
"Either no characters were extracted, or the characters extracted could not be interpreted as a valid value of the appropriate type"

So the empty string will trigger a fail. (checked and rdstate is 6, ie eof|fail);

**3) side question : value in case of error :**

Testing it, I tried an error case when setting an int. I called my function with a zero-initialized int, and an empty string :

```
int timeout=0;
getValue ("", timeout);

getValue : ''
type : i
result : 60000
ss.rdstate() : 6
```

This 60 000 value looks very weird to me. it corresponds to the init value of another int.. WTF ! 
For sure I am checking the result, but some other users may not. Should I enable the exceptions on failbits?

Comment: Problem 1 can be solved by adding an overload that takes bool.

Comment: you mean specializing the template for bool, and there check if '1' or if 'true' manually ?

Comment: I'd overload it instead of specialize but yes.  Check if the size of `value` is one and if it is read it in regularly and if it isn't use `std::boolalpha`.